# How to bundle and import buffer npm package with aurelia-cli?

Tags: aurelia

In my ESNext aurelia-cli project, I'm trying to use an npm module called bs58. bs58 uses Node buffers, so I've included the npm buffer module for Buffer support in the browser. buffer depends on a couple of other modules, which I've also included.

In aurelia.json I've mapped out the packages and dependencies:

```
      ...
      {
        "name": "base64-js",
        "path": "../node_modules/base64-js",
        "main": "index"
      },
      {
        "name": "ieee754",
        "path": "../node_modules/ieee754",
        "main": "index"
      },
      {
        "name": "buffer",
        "path": "../node_modules/buffer",
        "main": "index",
        "deps": [
          "base64-js",
          "ieee754"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "base-x",
        "path": "../node_modules/base-x",
        "main": "index"
      },
      {
        "name": "bs58",
        "path": "../node_modules/bs58",
        "main": "index",
        "deps": [
          "base-x"
        ]
      }
      ...
```

Then in my code I have:

```
import bs58 from 'bs58';
...
bs58.decode(...);
```

When I call bs58.decode I get "Buffer is not defined".
I've tried importing buffer a few different ways, but nothing causes it to define the global Buffer object, e.g.

```
import 'buffer';
import Buffer from 'buffer';
import { Buffer} from 'buffer';
require('buffer');
```

What's the right way to include buffer with aurelia-cli?

Comment: Shot in the dark... try adding `"buffer"` to your list of deps for `bs58` since it seems that `bs58` depends on `buffer`.  Also, can you check if your `"main"` is actually `index.js` in the folder `../node_modules/buffer`?  It's not always index.  Make sure that `main` is pointing to the main JavaScript file you want to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the base-x package is looking for a global *Buffer* so give it one:

```
// aurelia.json
{
    "ieee754",
    "base64-js",
    "buffer",
    "base-x",
    "bs58"
}


// some js file
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
window.Buffer = Buffer;
import bs58 from 'bs58';
```